# how to calculate voltage between two points

Tags: thevenin

[image]

how to calculate voltage between A and B?

Comment: You can read all about it in your book. Where are you failing?

Comment: Homework questions with.no attempt at a solution are closed.

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! This appears to be a homework question. As such, you need to show us your work so far, and explain which part of the question you're having trouble with. For future reference: Homework questions on EE.SE enjoy/suffer a special treatment. We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic questions, and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your own. Otherwise, we would be doing you a disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time. See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036).

Answer (score 2):

We can only guide.

- You can use superposition theorem to find \$ V_{AB} \$ with only one voltage source at a time. Then add both to get net \$ V_{AB} \$ when both sources are present .
- Using KVL and ohms law, solve for all currents and then find \$ V_{AB} \$ by adding voltage drops/emfs, traversing through any path in the circuit from point B to A.