# how to calculate voltage thevenin

Tags: thevenin

[image]

I do Kirchhoff law then I found I1=232uA, I2=158uA, I3= 0,074uA

now I want to calculate voltage Thevenin (voltage between A and B)?

I do like this 0.000232 * 10000=3.23

but I 3.23 not correct

Can you guide me

Comment: There is nothing marked I1, I2 or I3 on your diagram.

Comment: ok I will change it

Comment: Have you just created a new account to post this question because you didn't get the answer you wanted here: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/362175/how-to-calculate-voltage-between-two-points

Answer (score 0):

if 10 kohms = ***R*** and current thru it is ***I*** , :-

\$ V_{AB} = 10 - IR \$ , If direction of I is assumed to be towards the node ***A***.

\$ V_{AB} = 10 + IR \$ , If direction of I is assumed to be away from the node ***A***.

Comment: You are welcome :-).